# Сохранение JSON ответа в сsv. Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, парсер, csv

В общем сохраняю json ответ в сsv, получается как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге хочу достигнуть такой результат. Подскажите как реализовать(желательно с примером), или литературу какую-нибудь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice
from time import sleep
from random import uniform
import json
import csv

def get_html(url,useragent,proxy,StartFroms):
    #print("get_html")
    #print(StartFroms)
    #print(proxy)
    #print(useragent)
    s = requests.Session()
    s.get("http://toto-info.co",proxies = proxy)

    pl = {"options": {"DrawingId": 632, "StartFrom":StartFroms, "Count": 20, "SortField": "CouponCode", "SortDir": "ASC"}}
    res = s.post(url, headers={'User-Agent':useragent,
                'Accept-Language' : 'ru,en;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
                'Connection': 'keep - alive',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Host': 'old.toto-info.co',
                'Origin': 'http://toto-info.co',
                'Referer': 'http://toto-info.co/'},proxies = proxy, data=json.dumps(pl))

    data = res.json()

    with open('response.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

    print('------------------------------------------')

def main():

    url = 'http://old.toto-info.co/DataService.svc/GetMaxPrizeCoupons'

    useragents = open("useragents.txt").read().split('\n')
    proxies = open("proxies.txt").read().split('\n')

    start = 0 # переменная для хранения точки входа в for
    finish = 1000

    while start < finish:
        try:
            for i in range(start, finish, 20):
              a = (uniform(1, 2))
              sleep(a)
              StartFroms = i
              useragent = "'" + choice(useragents) + "'"
              proxy = {'http': 'http://' + choice(proxies)}
              get_html(url, useragent, proxy, StartFroms)
        except:
            start = i # перезапускаем for c точки исключения

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Извращенство какое-то :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий скрипт. Для теста я указал `finish = 100` (чтобы быстрее отработало):

```
import requests
from random import choice
from time import sleep
from random import uniform
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd

def get_html(url, useragent, proxy, StartFroms):

    s = requests.Session()
    s.get("http://toto-info.co")

    pl = {"options": {"DrawingId": 632, "StartFrom":StartFroms, "Count": 20, "SortField": "CouponCode", "SortDir": "ASC"}}
    resp = s.post(url, headers={'User-Agent':useragent,
                'Accept-Language' : 'ru,en;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
                'Connection': 'keep - alive',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Host': 'old.toto-info.co',
                'Origin': 'http://toto-info.co',
                'Referer': 'http://toto-info.co/'},proxies = proxy, data=json.dumps(pl))

    return resp.json()['d']['Items']

def main():

    url = 'http://old.toto-info.co/DataService.svc/GetMaxPrizeCoupons'

    useragents = open(r"D:\download\useragents.txt").read().split('\n')
    proxies = open(r"D:\download\proxies.txt").read().split('\n')

    start = 0 # переменная для хранения точки входа в for
    finish = 100
    data = []

    while start < finish:
        try:
            sleep(uniform(1, 2))
            useragent = "'{}'".format(choice(useragents))
            proxy = {'http': 'http://{}'.format(choice(proxies))}

            print('processing:\t[{}] ...'.format(start))
            data += get_html(url, useragent, proxy, start)
            start += 20

        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception:\t{}'.format(str(e)))


    print('building DataFrame ...')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # debug: print first 5 rows of DF...
    #print(df.head())


    out_fn = r'd:/temp/result.xlsx'

    df.set_index('CouponCode')['Options'] \
      .str.extractall(r'\d+-\((.*?)\)')[0] \
      .unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1) \
      .to_excel(out_fn, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за помощь, сам бы точно не разобрался.
и ещё, могло ли оно не работать, из за того, что у меня модуль "openpyxl" не был импортирован?

Comment: ЕМНИП по умолчанию Pandas использует `xlwt` модуль. `print(pd.show_versions())` - покажет все модули, которые Pandas может использовать...

Comment: оказалось "openpyxl" он тоже использует, вероятно тот код не работал из за того что не было ни xlwt, ни openpyxl. Теперь буду повнимательнее смотреть на exceptions. Огромно спасибо ещё раз

Answer (score 2):

Взял код автора, немного упростил и получил json. Сам код:

```
import json
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.get("http://toto-info.co")

pl = {"options": {"DrawingId": 632, "StartFrom": 1, "Count": 10, "SortField": "CouponCode", "SortDir": "ASC"}}
rs = session.post(
    url='http://old.toto-info.co/DataService.svc/GetMaxPrizeCoupons',
    headers={
        'Accept-Language': 'ru,en;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'Connection': 'keep - alive',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Host': 'old.toto-info.co',
        'Origin': 'http://toto-info.co',
        'Referer': 'http://toto-info.co/'
    },
    data=json.dumps(pl)
)

with open('response.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(rs.json(), f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

После считал json построчно и сохранил в excel:

```
import xlwt

with open('response.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Json data')

    for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        line = line.rstrip()
        ws.write(i, 0, line)

    wb.save('excel.xls')
```

Вот так выглядит excel:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл с json:

```
{
  "d": {
    "Summary": {
      "TotalCount": 93977,
      "__type": "SelectSummary:#FonbetEngine.DAL"
    },
    "__type": "SelectResultOfWinCouponSelectSummaryWVcc8KbY:#FonbetEngine.DAL",
    "Items": [
      {
        "MaxResult": 6,
        "CouponCode": "10000",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 0,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(X); 2-(1); 3-(2); 4-(2); 5-(1); 6-(X); 7-(2); 8-(1); 9-(1); 10-(2); 11-(1); 12-(2); 13-(X); 14-(X); 15-(2)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 2,
        "CouponCode": "100002",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 0,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(1); 2-(X); 3-(1); 4-(1); 5-(1); 6-(2); 7-(1); 8-(1); 9-(2); 10-(2); 11-(1); 12-(X); 13-(1); 14-(1); 15-(1)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 3,
        "CouponCode": "100019",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 0,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(2); 2-(2); 3-(X); 4-(1); 5-(1); 6-(X); 7-(2); 8-(2); 9-(X); 10-(1); 11-(1); 12-(X); 13-(2); 14-(2); 15-(X)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 5,
        "CouponCode": "100026",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 0,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(2); 2-(1); 3-(1); 4-(X); 5-(1); 6-(2); 7-(X); 8-(1); 9-(X); 10-(2); 11-(2); 12-(1); 13-(X); 14-(2); 15-(2)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 10,
        "CouponCode": "100033",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 961.6088,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(2); 2-(2); 3-(2); 4-(2); 5-(X); 6-(2); 7-(1); 8-(2); 9-(1); 10-(X); 11-(2); 12-(1); 13-(2); 14-(2); 15-(2)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 5,
        "CouponCode": "100040",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 0,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(2); 2-(X); 3-(1); 4-(2); 5-(1); 6-(1); 7-(1); 8-(2); 9-(X); 10-(X); 11-(1); 12-(2); 13-(X); 14-(1); 15-(X)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 6,
        "CouponCode": "100057",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 0,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(2); 2-(2); 3-(1); 4-(X); 5-(1); 6-(1); 7-(X); 8-(2); 9-(X); 10-(X); 11-(1); 12-(1); 13-(1); 14-(X); 15-(X)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 9,
        "CouponCode": "100064",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 341.1707,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(2); 2-(1); 3-(X); 4-(1); 5-(X); 6-(1); 7-(X); 8-(2); 9-(X); 10-(1); 11-(2); 12-(1); 13-(1); 14-(2); 15-(1)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 4,
        "CouponCode": "100071",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 0,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(2); 2-(2); 3-(1); 4-(1); 5-(2); 6-(X); 7-(1); 8-(1); 9-(2); 10-(1); 11-(X); 12-(1); 13-(2); 14-(2); 15-(1)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      },
      {
        "MaxResult": 5,
        "CouponCode": "100088",
        "TotalPrizeValue": 0,
        "__type": "WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity",
        "Cnt": 1,
        "Options": "1-(1); 2-(2); 3-(2); 4-(1); 5-(1); 6-(X); 7-(2); 8-(2); 9-(X); 10-(1); 11-(1); 12-(2); 13-(1); 14-(X); 15-(X)",
        "TotalStakeValue": 50
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за JSON файл!

Answer (score 2):

Трудно найти модуль для обработки табличных данных, который смог бы превзойти [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import json
import pandas as pd

# если: `data = res.json()`, т.е. `data` - словарь (parsed to dictionary JSON)        
df = pd.DataFrame(data['d']['Items'])

# если `json_str` - строка содержащая JSON response ...
#df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(json_str)['d']['Items'])

df.set_index('CouponCode')['Options'] \
  .str.extractall(r'\d+-\((.*?)\)')[0] \
  .unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1) \
  .to_excel('d:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Результат (`D:\temp\result.xlsx`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Распарсенный" в DataFrame JSON:

```
In [303]: df
Out[303]:
   Cnt CouponCode  MaxResult                        Options  TotalPrizeValue  \
0    1      10000          6  1-(X); 2-(1); 3-(2); 4-(2)...           0.0000
1    1     100002          2  1-(1); 2-(X); 3-(1); 4-(1)...           0.0000
2    1     100019          3  1-(2); 2-(2); 3-(X); 4-(1)...           0.0000
3    1     100026          5  1-(2); 2-(1); 3-(1); 4-(X)...           0.0000
4    1     100033         10  1-(2); 2-(2); 3-(2); 4-(2)...         961.6088
5    1     100040          5  1-(2); 2-(X); 3-(1); 4-(2)...           0.0000
6    1     100057          6  1-(2); 2-(2); 3-(1); 4-(X)...           0.0000
7    1     100064          9  1-(2); 2-(1); 3-(X); 4-(1)...         341.1707
8    1     100071          4  1-(2); 2-(2); 3-(1); 4-(1)...           0.0000
9    1     100088          5  1-(1); 2-(2); 3-(2); 4-(1)...           0.0000

   TotalStakeValue                   __type
0               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
1               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
2               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
3               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
4               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
5               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
6               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
7               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
8               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
9               50  WinCoupon:#FonbetEntity
```

Comment: В общем я добавил твой код, и не сработало, что может быть не так?@MaxU

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/SGsysAz03Ja3CY это что я получаю, если пишу print(resp.json()) @MaxU

Comment: @ПашаВасильев, хмм... вы его в таком виде и получили? https://jsonlint.com/ утверждает что это "invalid JSON" Вы можете сохранить файл: `open('/path/to/file.json', 'w').write(resp.text)` ?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/rxbt-D2D3Ja4Ts вот сохранил ещё раз, как вы сказали

Comment: попробовал, тоже ничего

Comment: а что значит "ничего"? Я сейчас проверил у меня все работает с вышими данными

Comment: Ну т.е нет этого файл, он его как бы не создаёт.

Comment: и вот ещё когда я вывожу data просто в консоль, то там json в одинарных кавычках, а когда мы записывали как вы сказали идут двойные, может ли это как-то повлиять.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/b-GhAbhr3Ja5tB вот питон файл и  useragent c proxy 
https://yadi.sk/i/Ls2bLcgI3Ja5tG
https://yadi.sk/i/bpXtSKqH3Ja5tN
я всё сделал как вы сказали, можете взглянуть @MaxU

Comment: я бы посоветовал для начала отключить перехват "exceptions", чтобы увидеть ошибки... PS Я надеюсь у вас есть папка: `d:\temp`? Если нет, то вам надо поменять путь на ваш...

Comment: да папку то я менял

Comment: @ПашаВасильев, вы хотите собрать все данные в один Excel или записывать отдельный Excel для каждого `StartFroms`?

Comment: Все данные в один Excel @MaxU